# Check if UDP port is open with ICMP in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, icmp, raw-sockets

I am trying to check if a specific UDP port is open or not. I am trying to do this by sending UDP packets and checking the ICMP response to see if the UDP port is avaiable or not. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>   /* inet(3) functions */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXLINE 10096

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd, portno;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    struct hostent *server;
    int sendfd, recvfd;
    
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if (server == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //socket varibles
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;  
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    //get port from command line arguments
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr);

    // open send UDP socket
    if((sendfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
     {
       perror("*** socket(,,IPPROTO_UDP) failed ***n");
       exit(-1);
     }
     // open receive ICMP socket
     if((recvfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) < 0)
     {
       perror("*** socket(,,IPPROTO_ICMP) failed ***n");
       exit(-1);
     }

    
    
    int n;
    char sendline[] = "a message";  //string for message to be sent
    char recvline[MAXLINE];     //string for message to be received

         
    //send ping request
    if(sendto(sendfd, sendline, sizeof(sendline), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("*** sendto() failed ***");
    }
    
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 100000;
    if (setsockopt(recvfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,&tv,sizeof(tv)) < 0) {
        perror("Error");
    }
    
    n = recvfrom(recvfd, recvline, MAXLINE, 0, NULL, NULL);
    recvline[n] = '\0';    /* null terminate */

    struct iphdr *ip_hdr = (struct iphdr *)recvline;
    int iplen = ip_hdr->ihl << 2;
    struct icmphdr *icmp = (struct icmphdr *)((char *)ip_hdr + (4 * ip_hdr->ihl));
              
    if((icmp->type == ICMP_UNREACH) && (icmp->code == ICMP_UNREACH_PORT))
    {
     printf("\nPORT CLOSED\n"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nPORT OPEN\n");    
    }
        


    exit(0);
}
```

How can I get this working? When I run the code, It always says "PORT OPEN" in every port I test it with which definitely cannot be right.

Comment: First of all, please add error checking for the `recvfrom` call. Secondly please use a debugger to step through the code, and check what the contents of the IP and ICMP structures are.

Comment: Are you sure the server is sending ICMP Port Unreachable? Use `tcpdump` to check.

Comment: You don't need raw socksts for this. Just connect to the target and send a few times and see if you get an error.

Comment: Probably for security reasons or perhaps because the local firewall swallows the packet first, ICMP responses aren't sent by all operating systems when an unopen port is hit.  I remember my early socket programming days with SunOS and Solaris - after a local socket hit an unopen port, a subsequent `recvfrom` or `sendto` would fail with a specific errno if the remote peer had sent back an ICMP.   But when I was doing some pretty deep UDP programming a few years back, I recall that most, if not all, modern operating systems don't do ICMP.  Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @selbie You may have found, or overlooked, that you can't get the ICMP response as an error unless the socket is connected, because otherwise the OS doesn't know where to put it.

Comment: @user207421 The obvious drawback from that is that UDP is unreliable, the packets being sent could be dropped without notifications. Sure, the more packets that are being sent the chances of that happening will approach zero, but it will never be exactly zero.

Comment: Just wondering why you are setting the server address from the host in the bcopy statement and then overwriting it with argv[1] in the inet_pton statement.

Comment: @user207421 - I think I had wireshark up for some casual tests between UDP server and client. And specifically tested the closed server port scenario. Don't recall ICMP.  But I could be mistaken or the ICMP gets swallowed up by a router somewhere.

Comment: Shouldn't the sendfd protocol type be IPPROTO_ICMP?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's a problem with alll possible solutions, not just mine. If no packets arrive, no ICMP responses can be generated.

Comment: @cup that doesn't work. For some reason sending with sendfd fails when I switch to IPPROTO_ICMP

Comment: @cup Obviously not. Maybe the *receiving* protocol should be ICMP, but he is sending UDP, not ICMP.